# Send message delay in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I want all the emails I send to be scheduled to be sent 5 minutes later, to safe guard from blunders (I know I can undo sending for 30 seconds, I want more time). In Outlook I did it using rules that add a delay, I couldn't find a way to do it in Gmail. I'm in a Linux environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217346/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-mail-using-gmail-api#:~:text=The%20Gmail%20API%20has%20no,the%20App%20Engine%20Cron%20Service. Answer from another stackoverflow universe

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, there is something called scheduled send. For setting this as the default behavior, I'm not sure if that's possible.

[image]

After selecting Schedule Send (and having a recipient inputted), the following prompt will show up allowing you to choose when to send the email.

[image]

You can choose the defaults or set your own by choosing  Pick Time and Date. Pressing Pick Time and Date will show the following prompt.

[image]

Note: It appears that you cannot set a scheduled mail to be sent in 2 minutes or less, it has to be at least 3 minutes.

You can cancel any scheduled mail by going into this your sidebar and looking for the Scheduled tab.

[image]

You can navigate to one of your scheduled emails then press the Cancel Send Button.
[image]